# Why would Anakin Skywalker trust Chancellor Palpatine?

Tags: star-wars, anakin-skywalker

Why would Anakin Skywalker trust Chancellor Palpatine once he knew Palpatine was a Sith Lord?

In one scene of Revenge of the Sith, Palpatine invites Anakin to chat with him and reveals a legend about a Sith Lord that could save the people he cared about from death. (That alone should have been a big honking clue that Palpatine was a Sith Lord or in cahoots with one). Later when Anakin finally figures out that Palpatine is a Sith Lord, why would he trust anything Palpatine ever said to him? The safest assumption is that Palpatine was lying and manipulative. So when Palpatine, almost beaten by Mace Windu, says "only I can save the one you love", Anakin should have replied with "What!? You expect me to believe that? You're a sociopath!"

**Edit:** This is different from asking why Anakin believed turning to the Dark Side of the Force would save Padmé? For Anakin to believe Palpatine could help him save Padmé, he would first have to trust Palpatine. Once you know somebody is a murderous, lying, manipulative dictator, there is no reason to believe any word he ever said.

Comment: I feel like this question was already asked somewhere. In any event, related: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K2ScVx4mRDE&t=1m10s

Comment: @ellesdil - Seems like a dupe to me. The only thing not mentioned is Anakin's deep long term relationship with Palpatine.